# Dropzone - do something if the user has climbed unaccepted files

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropzone.js

I want to detect if a user upload an unaccepted file and do some action.

**CODE JS:**

```
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
    var myDropzone = new Dropzone("div#myDrop", {
        url             : "<?php echo $this->serverUrl() . '/profile/ajax/dzupload'; ?>",
        paramName       : 'patientprofilepicture',
        acceptedFiles   : "image/*",
        maxFiles        : 1,
        addRemoveLinks  : true,
        init            : function() {

this.on('unaccepted files', function(file, xhr, formData){
            dosomething()
    });
});
```

Something like this is possible?
Is there any function to detect this?

Thanks in advance!